# error : CorePlot0 does not contain a valid pid for core plot

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I am trying to integrate coreplot in my mac application.

Anyone having easy steps to integrate it?

I got the sample code from here.
[core plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)

Nut when i tried to integrated core plot with my own application it is giving me this error. There is also one document for following the steps but I am not getting it.If any one has any other steps in understanding language then please suggest me its urgent for me.

Till now I have followed this.

- Added its framework folder to my application folder.
- I added coreplot to my target dependency and built phase->link binary with libraries
- I also set other linker flag -all_load, -ObjC

What other steps are remain? so that it is giving this error?

Somewhere I found solution to delete this file `checkformisalignedlayers.d` file but it is creating new errors after deleting it.

I also found suggestion as to set header search path but didn't get how to set that because I have added whole framework folder to my application because when I drag & drop only .xcodeproject it was not allowing me to import its files.

Comment: Have you followed all of the instructions on the [Core Plot wiki](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications#Mac_Application)?

Answer (score 1):

I followed this [tutorial](http://recycled-parts.blogspot.in/2011/08/coreplot-hello-world.html) for `CorePlot`. 
I got the same problem, but i did import like,

1. Add only `TestResources, Source, and iPhoneOnly Folders` and `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h`
2. Search For **Tests** in your `project resources` and Remove all files named `test` under your `Source folder`.
3. Remove `checkformisalignedlayers.d` in your `TestResources` folder.
4. Run `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj` and `CorePlot.xcodeproj` Separately. You'll find `build` folder.
5. In that `build` folder, you'll find `CorePlot.framework` under your `Debug` folder and `libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a` under your `Debug-iphoneos` folder.
6. Open your `Project -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries` and Drag & Drop the `CorePlot.framework` and `libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a` there.
7. Add these `-all_load and -ObjC` flag in your `Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags` section.
8. Add `QuartzCore framework`.

**Note:**
After Completing this process, delete your `Derived Data` in your `Organizer` and `Clean` the `Build`.